# ToolTip for own drawings

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, tooltip

my java application contains a JPanel on which I draw certain shapes. Now I would like to label these shapes with some kind of tooltips.

Therefore I tried to create my own "Tooltips" by using the drawString, setBackground, setColor method.:

```
public void drawToolTip(Graphics2D graphics, String text, Point2D position) {
    graphics.setBackground(Color.RED);
    graphics.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    graphics.drawString(text, (float) position.getX(), (float) position.getY());
}
```

Unfortunately the setBackground method does not seem to work. The text background remains transparent although I set it to red. setColor and drawString just work fine.

My questions are:

- What could be the reason that the setBackground method does not work?
- Is there a possibility to draw a boarder arround the text without drawRect?
- If I want to use "drawRect" method as a substitude to draw the text background and border: How can I make it automatically fit to the written text? Or in other words how can I get the dimensions of a specific text?

Regards Marc

Comment: How are you getting that Graphics2D object by the way? Is it from a BufferedImage? Are you calling `getGraphics()` or `createGraphics()` on a component?

Comment: In the paint method of a JPanel I do:
Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;

and call the drawToolTip method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Graphics2D.drawString()` does not draw a background by default. You will have to do this yourself.
- You can use `drawRect()` to draw a line border or `fillRec()` to draw a solid rectangle.
- Oracle has a great [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) on measuring String widths. Essentially, you need to create a `java.awt.Font` then get its `FontMetrics` and use that to calculate the width and height of your string.

Comment: Also, make sure that you call `Graphics2D.setFont()` so that you're actually drawing the `String` with the same font you got the `FontMetrics` for.

Answer (score 3):

A simple implementation would involve drawing onto the `Graphics` object of a `JLabel`'s icon. And then simply adding the tool tip text to the Swing component.

For more information, see [How to Use Tool Tips](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can not change background color the way you expect using `graphics.setBackground(..)` call. Setting background color in the Graphics2D only affects the clearRect or fillRect kind of calls and not the background color of the Component.

For drawing a rectangle at a location you wish, with specific back ground, you will have to relay on following steps:

1. Define a rectangle - `r`
2. `grpahics.setPaint()` for background and
3. `graphics.fill(r)` `graphcis.setPaint()` for border and
4. `graphics.draw(r)` to draw border

now, comes the difficult part of drawing text in to the rectangle which involves computation of height etc. based on `FontMetrics` of the font you would set for drawing the text. 
I googled and found an example for you [here](http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/19053-draw-string-rectangle.html)